# Feathersjs retrieve foreign key value through API

Tags: postgresql, knex.js, feathersjs

I am using PostgresSQL database with Feathersjs, connecting both through Knex. The database table (NewTable) was created with a foreign key, referencing to the users services.

Following describe the database table.

```
module.exports = function (app) {
  const db = app.get('knexClient');
  db.schema.createTableIfNotExists('NewTable', table => {
    table.increments('id').primary();
    table.integer('ownerId').references('users.id');
  })
```

I will receive the foreign key value of ownerId (in integer) when I query it through GET.

```
export function load(id) {
  return {
    types: [LOAD, LOAD_SUCCESS, LOAD_FAIL],
    promise: ({ app }) => app.service('NewTable').get(id)
  };
}
```

What is the proper way to retrieve the first_name column of the user instead of userId through the GET api?

Do I need to run another GET api within the hook of NewTable service to get the first_name column, or there is a better/easier way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a function like below within the hook of feathersjs.

```
function populateUser() {
  return populate({
    schema: {
      include: [{
        nameAs: 'sentBy',
        service: 'users',
        parentField: 'ownerId',
        childField: 'id'
      }]
    }
  });
}
```

Use it within the hook to call it after the GET. The columns of user service will be included within the response.

```
after: {
  all: [],
  find: [],
  get: [
    populateUser(),
    }
  ],
  create: [],
  update: [],
  patch: [],
  remove: []
},
```